# Custom layout for dhtml scheduler

Tags: scheduler, dhtmlx

I was using DHTMLX Scheduler in my MVC project. Everything is fine. But the default scheduler is occupying full screen space. And i am not able to include my own layout with Scheduler. Is there any possibilities to make this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scheduler occupies full size of its container,
so you may wrap it with an element of predefined size, e.g.

```
<div style="height:500px;width:700px"> <%= Scheduler.Render() %> </div>
```

Or you can explicitly set sizes of the scheduler

```
scheduler.Height = 500;
scheduler.Width = 700;
```

Comment: I have given this scheduler size. but still no change

Comment: I've just checked it with the latest version of the lib - sizes gets applied to the scheduler, maybe i've misunderstood the problem.
Anyway, you can download sample from this blog post, calendar is used with a layout there(you'll have to subscribe for a blogs newsletter to download it)
http://blog.scheduler-net.com/post/2012/06/15/creating-car-rental-application-in-asp-net-mvc3-razor.aspx

Comment: btw, are you using client-side scheduler, or dhtmlxScheduler for .Net, which goes with DHTMLX.dll ?

Comment: if it's client-side scheduler, you may just modify styles of calendars markup root, by default it has width and height set to 100% - 
<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
...
</div>

Comment: I am using client side scheduler. If i set some size for scheduler like, **<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="width:30%; height:60%;">**. Scheduler is not showing with the window

Answer (score 2):

Trying this format get my problem solved.

```
`<div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style="height:1000px;width:1075px">`.
```

You have setup height and width of the Scheduler container. This solved my issue.